# import a common folder using webpack 2

Tags: webpack-2

I have the following file structures:

```
core
.... src
........ common
............ common.js

someProject
.... node_modules
.... src
........ someModule   
............ index.js
webpack.config.js
```

In index.js, I want to be able to do something like:

```
import { bla } from 'common/common.js';
```

I tried using an **alias**, but then I need to install node_modules in **core** and **someProject** to make it work. I want to install node_modules only in **someProject**.

Is alias the right approach or do I need to use something different?

Here is my resolve object from webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        path.resolve('./src')
    ],
    alias: {
        common: path.resolve('../core/src/common')
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting: `Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-node-env-inline" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to ...` but once I install "transform-node-env-inline", this error is resolved and I get another one, the only way I'm able to resolve it is to install all npm modules.

Answer (score 0):

Set it up as a module the same way you have `src`. This is how I have my config setup, which worked much better for me than trying to use alias. I don't think it should matter where your node_modules are, but I'm not entirely sure since I have mine installed in the root directory. If this doesn't work because of the way you have your directories set up, I would suggest just installing node_modules in the root of the project with your webpack.config.js instead of inside `someProject`. I just can't be sure this will work without trying it.

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'js'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'js', 'modules'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'js', 'components'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'js', 'util'),
        'node_modules',
    ],
    alias: {},
    extensions: ['.js'],
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, still getting the same errors, and I can't change the file structure.

Comment: Give me a minute, let me try to setup a project in this way and see if I can get it to work. What is your error, just that it cannot find the file? EDIT: I don't really understand why you can't change the file structure...moving node_modules should, I would think, be a rather trivial move.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I added the error to the question.

Comment: Hmm. I see the issue, I think. I am having no problem importing the file, but it's not being run through babel and the file doesn't seem to know where to find the node_modules. I resolved that by simply changing the `import`/`require` to an absolute path, but it doesn't seem to be implementing webpack's functionality, it's just importing the file without any filters. Let me mess around and see if I can figure out how to resolve this.

Comment: The way I have this setup is slightly different from yours. Just enough so that I think it's skewing the dir paths. I have a feeling it has to do with the `context` perhaps, but I would need to set it up exactly like you have it to debug it correctly and unfortunately I don't have the time to do that right now. I know you said you can't, but choosing a different dir structure would more than likely be the easiest solution to this by far. If you or no one else has been able to resolve this once I have some time later tonight, I'll take another more comprehensive look/test.